# iMessage to contact always goes to group chat

Tags: ios, ichat

This is happening on my son's phone. Whenever he tries to send an iMessage to my wife, it adds 3 of his friends to the conversation and sends it as a group chat. This happens regardless of how he initiates the message.

Pressing on the Group icon at the top of the Message window closes the Messages app.

Looking at Contacts, there are no groups there.

If my wife sends a text to him, it shows as only going to him on her phone, but on his phone it goes to the group.

The group replies to these texts, so we know that they are getting them.

My son is running the latest iOS.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Mobile phones are off topic here except insofar as the problem is in connecting to a computer. If your problem is with an Android phone then you might want to ask at [Android.se] otherwise for iPhone there is [apple.se].